# FB link removing fbclid Ipads IOS

Tags: javascript, php

Having a problem my site linking directly from Facebook.

It seems to be caused from the "fbclid" get request query parameter that Facebook is adding to the link.

I have added the below JS

```
(function() {
var param = 'fbclid';
if (location.search.indexOf(param + '=') !== -1) {
        var replace = '';
        try {
                var url = new URL(location);
                url.searchParams.delete(param);
                replace = url.href;
        } catch (ex) {
                var regExp = new RegExp('[?&]' + param + '=.*$');
                replace = location.search.replace(regExp, '');
                replace = location.pathname + replace + location.hash;
        }
        history.replaceState(null, '', replace);
}
```

})();

This seems to be working for 90% of users but some IOS users are reporting issues.

Is there any reason this wouldn't work for them?

Comment: Are you using Apache or Nginx? Do you have access to the .htaccess file?

Comment: I have access to the .htaccess file and we are using Apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some older versions of iOS might not have support for the History API.

It would be gross, but you could just redirect users on the client side using

```js
window.location.replace(replace);
```

A better solution would be to rewrite the URL on the server side using the web server or application logic.

Comment: This could be a possible workaround until I come up with a more permanent fix.  Thank you